# how to create a list of integers from a text file with multiple lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

I need to write a program that reads a text file and returns the median of the numbers in the file. I think I have a good idea of how to approach this, but I got an AttributeError when running my program.

My question is: how do I make one list for the numbers in the text file? There are a total of 15 numbers, split across 5 lines in the file:

10 20 30 
40 50 60 
90 80 70 
11 22 13 
14 14 20

what I thought to do to create a list was:

```
num_list = fv.readlines()
num_list = num_list.split()
```

I thought this would read through all the lines of the file, then I could use the split function to create a list of the numbers. Now that I got an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split', I'm unsure of what to do.

Comment: `num_list = [int(x) for x in fv.read().split()]`.

Comment: thanks for this reply, this ended up working!

Answer (score 2):

Without a solid expected result I assume you want all numbers in one list.

You can create an empty list then use `list.extend` as you loop through the file. You will need to cast them to int though. `map` is great for this:

```
num_list = []
with open('filename.txt') as fv:
    for row in fv:
        num_list.extend(map(int, row.split()))
```

More efficiently you can use `re`

```
import re

with open('filename.txt') as fv:
    num_list = list(map(int, re.findall('\d+', fv.read())))
```

Result *(for both above)* will be:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 90, 80, 70, 11, 22, 13, 14, 14, 20]
```

---

Otherwise in sublists by line/row:

```
with open('filename.txt') as fv:
    num_list = [list(map(int, row.split())) for row in fv]
```

Result for this:

```
[[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [90, 80, 70], [11, 22, 13], [14, 14, 20]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you want to do:

```
lines = fv.readlines()
num_list = []

for line in lines:
    num_list.extend(line.split(' '))

num_list = [int(num.strip()) for num in num_list]
```

Answer (score -1):

My answer is definitely a longer version but...

```
text = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
string = text.read()
string = string.replace('\n', ' ')
numbers = string.split(' ')
text.close()

#Print to see the result
print(numbers)
```